# Is there a "$\text{sinc}$" function for $\cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question, notation

Is there are function to represent $x\mapsto\frac{\cos x}{x}$ as there is for $\sin x$, namely $\frac{\sin x}{x}=\text{sinc }x$?

Comment: At $0$, it is not indeterminate!

Comment: If there was one, it would rather be $$\cos x:=2\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}.$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust How so? $1-\cos x=2\sin^2(x/2)$ so that your $\cos x:=4\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}=4\text{ sinc$^2$ }x$, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There is $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$, this is common in literature.

Comment: @user3482534: the second $c$ of $\text{cosc}$ somehow disappeared. Mystery... Now, you probably discovered why there is no need for a $\text{cosc}$.

Comment: Even $\frac{1-\cos x}x$ can be written as $\frac{x\operatorname{sinc}^2x}{1+\cos x}$.

Comment: The Julia language [defines](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Math.cosc) a function $\mathrm{cosc}(x)$ as the **derivative** of $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$.   Analytically, $\mathrm{cosc}(x) = \frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}$, whose limit is $0$ as $x \to 0$.  Numerically, however, this "cosc" function turns out to be quite tricky to implement [accurately without catastrophic cancellation error](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/37227).  Practically, this cosc is therefore useful to enable e.g. [differentiable programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_programming).

Comment: Sinc is sin divided by its polynomial first term. If we follow this logic for all the trigonometric/hyperbolic functions, we get that cos, cosh, sec, sech should be divided by 1 (giving us the same function back), sin, sinh, tan, tanh should be divided by x (which is how sinc, sinch, tanc, tanch are defined normally), and csc, csch, cot, coth should be multiplied by x.

All these functions satisfy f(-x) = f(x) and f(0) = 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The motivation for functions such as $\text{sinc}x,\,\text{sinch}x,\,\text{tanc}x,\,\text{tanch}x$ is to consider the behaviour of a ratio with limit $1$ as $x\to 0$. There is no such motivation for $\frac{\cos x}{x}$, since $\cos0 =1\ne 0$. However, you can [write this ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral) as $-\text{Ci}' \left( x\right)$.